# Why am I getting an "use of undefined type" error in my code, when I have the header for it included?

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I'm learning C++ and am trying to write a simple game, using Direct3D. In my game project, I use a single namespace throughout my game, named `GameEngine`. My game logic is contained within a main class, named `Game`. That `Game` class will have member variables for things like the input manager and object manager. These will be private members, but I have a public function on my `Game` class that returns a pointer to the `InputManager` class. That way, I can tell the `InputManager` to handle window messages inside of my main `PeekMessage` loop of the program.

Here's my main message loop ...

```
// instanciate the game
GameEngine::Game game(windowRectangle.bottom, windowRectangle.right);

// initialize D3D
game.InitializeDirect3D(hWnd);
game.InitializePipeline();

// main game loop
while (true)
{
    // check for received event messages
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        bool handled = false;

        if (msg.message >= WM_MOUSEFIRST && msg.message <= WM_MOUSELAST)
        {
            handled = game.GetInputManager()->HandleMouseInput(&msg);
        }
        else if (msg.message >= WM_KEYFIRST && msg.message <= WM_KEYLAST)
        {
            handled = game.GetInputManager()->HandledKeyboardInput(&msg);
        }
        else if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (handled == false)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageA(&msg);
        }
    }

    // render the current frame
    game.RenderFrame();
}

// tear down D3D
game.CleanDirect3D();
```

I'm getting an error when I call `GetInputManager`, though. It says I'm using an undefined type `InputManager`. The `GetInputManager` function returns a pointer to an `InputManager`. At the top of my `Main.cpp` file, in which this main message loop resides, I include the header that contains the definition of `InputManager`, which is `InputManager.h`. So, I'm not quite sure why it says this is an undefined type.

Does anybody know what this error is occurring? I'm trying to use forward declarations for the first time in some of these header files, and I'm thinking maybe it has to do with those?

I pasted the whole code, organized by file, on Github here: https://gist.github.com/ryancole/5936795#file-main-cpp-L27

The files are properly named and the error line is highlighted near the bottom of the paste.

Comment: It's in GameEngine namespace, do you have "using GameEngine" in your file?

Comment: Your include guards use [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Game.h` forward declares a `class InputManager` *in the global namespace*, but the real `InputManager` class is in namespace `GameEngine`.

Since the two declarations are in different namespaces they are independent of each other and the `InputManger` in the global namespace stays a incomplete type. To fix the problem, move the forward declaration into the namespace.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it. I wasn't fully aware of how to use forward declarations, but now I understand them better.